# Can I check if a PGP signed message has been modified when I don't have the public key

Tags: hash, signature

Is it possible to check if a PGP signed message has been modified when the public key of the signer is not available?

Like, is there a message digest (hash) that can be checked without knowing the public key of the signer?

Note that I am aware that, even if the message digest is *okay*, it is not possible to prove authenticity. However, what I am asking is if I can discover just the case that the message has been *modified* (more accidentally than intentionally tampered with).

Basically, I'm asking if I can technically detect a modification of a signed message without the signer's public key.

The reason why I am asking is this scenario:

- I get a message that is signed
- I don't have the signer's public key
- My app tells me that the signer cannot be verified

Now I modify one byte of the message and try again, then

- My app still tells me that the signer cannot be verified

while I would think that, in this scenario, it would be more important to know that the message has been modified.

Comment: If you are not able to verify the authenticity of a message, how can you trust any calculation of its integrity? Or to put it another way, if I have maliciously modified a signed message, couldn't I just as easily maliciously modify the checksum?

Comment: _Tampered with_ explicitly indicates _intentional_ modification, and that's not limited to cryptography. Further, in a cryptographic context, _altered_ also at least includes the possibility of intentional modification. If you are limited to accidental modification (as I now think you are), that should be more explicit in the question; the added "think of: " still does not make it clear enough.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks for the pointer. I'm not a native speaker, so perhaps that's why I wasn't aware of the narrow meaning of *tampered with*. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There is no cryptographically sound method to check if a PGP signed message has been *tampered with*† when the public key of the signer is not available.

Argument: an adversary can craft any message they like, sign it with a private key of their choice, and if encryption is used encipher it with the public key of the intended recipient(s), which by the standard definition of *public* is assumed available to adversaries.

---

There are several ways in which many (and for large messages at least, most) *accidental* alterations of the message can be detected (at least with knowledge of the public key of a recipient, or of the password for symmetrically encrypted data), including

- A 16-bit field of a signature packet [version 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-5.2.3) ([or 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-5.2.2)) designed specifically for this purpose.
- The [Modification Detection Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#page-52) which is designed for that purpose.
- The (little) redundancy built into the compression that is optionally used.
- And of course the redundancy in the message itself.

---

† The standard meaning of that is that an *intentional* modification has been applied. Further, in a cryptographic context, the default is to assume that alterations are deliberately made by intelligent adversaries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I said in my question, I am aware of the fact that any signer could have signed the message after having modified it. Yet, that's not what I'm after. I'm asking if I can detect a modification of the message without the signer's public key. I edited my question in the hope to make that clearer.

Comment: @not2savvy: The signing blob contains the first 16 bits of the hash of the message. This usually fast-rejects damaged messages.